# How to bind input value to object property in Blazor

Tags: c#, bind, blazor

I have a object property like this:
`public object Data { get; set; }`

And I have some input with different types in `.razor` component:

```
switch (DataType)
{
    case DataType.Boolean:
        <input @bind="Data" type="checkbox" />
        break;
    case DataType.String:
        <input @bind="Data" type="text" />
        break;
    case DataType.Number:
        <input @bind="Data" type="number" />
        break;
}
```

Аs a result I get error:

[image: The type System.Object does not have an associated TypeConverter that supports conversion from a string]

how can I bind these input to object property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and using `@onchange` instead of `@bind` resolved it.

```
switch (DataType)
{
    case DataType.Boolean:
        <input @onchange="@(x => { Data = x; })" type="checkbox" />
        break;
    case DataType.String:
        <input @onchange="@(x => { Data = x; })" type="text" />
        break;
    case DataType.Number:
        <input @onchange="@(x => { Data = x; })" type="number" />
        break;
}
```

Comment: How do you display a default value if you will not use @bind-value attribute?